# How to restrict internet usage with multiple Wi-Fi connections?

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, internet

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS with:

- Memory: 7.5 GiB
- Processor: Intel® Core™ i7-4600U CPU @ 2.10GHz × 4
- Graphics: Intel® Haswell Mobile
- GNOME: 3.28.2
- OS type: 64-bit

I am managing multiple networks using Wi-Fi connection with each with Wi-Fi USB dongle.

I have found an issue of internet speed when more two WiFi networks are connected to the system.

I want to use the internet of specific WiFi connection only and restrict the internet for other Wi-Fi Network.

Is there any way to do it?

Please note that each WiFi network is configured with DHCP.

I want to restrict the internet from system side (Not network side).

Comment: [link] https://www.quora.com/unanswered/How-do-I-restrict-internet-usage-with-multiple-Wi-Fi-connections

Comment: @kulfy Thank You for correction